# この指数関数についての方程式はどのように解けばいいでしょうか

Tags: python, python3, sympy

以下の指数関数のｘについての方程式はどのようにして解けばいいでしょうか？

```
exp(-1/x**2) = exp(-2/x**2) - exp(-3/x**2)
```

sympyのsolveメソッドを使ったのですが実行が無限に行われうまくいきませんでした。環境はjupyter notebookです。

Comment: どういうことについて知りたいのかをはっきりさせるため、知りたい問題をより具体的にしたり、追加の詳細を書き加えたりしてください。現状のままだと何についての質問なのかが分かりづらいです。

Answer (score 0):

これは

1. Sympyを使わないといけない問題なのでしょうか？
2. ただ単にｘについての方程式はどのようにして解けばいいでしょうか？

自分の理解が足りないだけかもしれませんが、
Sympyはそこまで複雑な数式を答えてくれるとは思っていません。

もし回答方法を知りたいのであれば、Stackoverflowの趣旨とは少し違いますが、
少しだけヒントをあげておきます。

両辺にLn(ナチュラルログ)を掛け、数式を２、３回展開するだけで解けると思いますよ。

Comment: xの値が得られればsympy でなくてもいいのですが、ほかに方法があるのか知りたくて質問させていただきました。Lnをかけて展開してもLn(1-exp(-a/x^2)) の項が残ってしまい解けなかったので、代数的に解けないものかと思いました。

Answer (score 0):

```
exp(-1/x**2) = exp(-2/x**2) - exp(-3/x**2)
```

`1/x**2` を `y` と置けば、

```
exp(-y) = exp(-2y) - exp(-3y)
```

少し変形すると、

```
exp(y) + exp(-y) = 1
```

グラフを描けば、解がないことがわかる。
ただしそれは実数の世界での話で、虚数を持ち込むなら、更に進める。

y=zi と置けば、

```
exp(zi) + exp(-zi) = 1
```

オイラーの公式を使って、

```
cos(z) + isin(z) + cos(-z) + isin(-z) = 1
```

求めると、

```
z = ±π/3 + 2πn    (n は整数)
```

元に戻っていって、

```
y = zi
  = (±π/3 + 2πn)i
```

```
1/x**2 = (±π/3 + 2πn)i
```

従って、

```
x = ±sqrt(1/(±π/3 + 2πn)i)
```

---

自信はないですが・・・

Answer (score 0):

[SymPy Live](https://live.sympy.org/) で解いてみるとこんな感じですね↓

<strike>文字数が足りない</strike>
[image: solve equation]